# Best way to store Configuration Data?

Tags: vb.net, configuration

I have developed a rather big Application in the last year. Since I am not a programmer by trade, I asked a fellow programmer how to store a huge amount of application settings - his answer was "use a configuration class". 
So I ended up with a "Constants.vb" file which contains literally thousands of configuration details. A lot of them are unlikely to change, but a few dozen of them could change and they should be changeable by the customer.
I am not satisfied with this mess, since it becomes harder to maintain by the minute - I have seen the my.settings / my.resources classes and I use them for some settings - but since there is no obvious way to organize the data, I am not keen to drop a ton of config variables into my.settings...
Do you have any Ideas for me?

Comment: One way is to use an XML file and serialize/deserialize the settings at runtime.

Comment: I have read various comments that the standard serialization technique of .NET is not recommended for long term storage because it may be unable to deserialize data from old versions.

Comment: Yes, but that's related to binary serialization, where the CLR is used and the assembly version may break compatibility. XML serialization depends on your XML schemes and does not suffer from this drawback. Besides that, the XML file can be edited with any editor, so if you add a property to your class, you could theoretically resort to editing the XML file by hand to include it.